# SQL Query: Get the minimal element, which is higher than one specific element

Tags: mysql, sql

i try to do a mysql query.

I have the following tables:

```
recordCard, which contains id, ... 
userToRecordCardData, which contains user_id, card_id (id from recordCard Table), win, fail...
```

now i have a given recordCardId := lastId.

And i want to get the id of the recordCard, where win/fail (divided) is minimal but bigger then win/fail from the lastId.

I have tried some querys with min(win/fail) etc. but i dont'really know how to do this special query. Can anyone help me? This would be awesome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
SELECT user_id
     , card_id 
     , win/fail win_fail_ration
  FROM userToRecordCardData
 WHERE win/fail > (SELECT win/fail FROM userToRecordCardData WHERE card_id = lastId)
 ORDER BY win/fail
 LIMIT 1
```

EDIT In the case of ties...

```
SELECT user_id
     , card_id 
     , win/fail win_fail_ration
  FROM userToRecordCardData
 WHERE win/fail >= (SELECT win/fail FROM userToRecordCardData WHERE card_id = lastId)
   AND card_id = lastId
 ORDER BY win/fail
       --,card_id DESC --as an example of further ordering your results.
 LIMIT 1
```

Comment: what if i need a ">=" because there are other entrys with the same win/fail ration but i still don't want the lastId as result?

Comment: Then use >= on and add AND card_id <> lastId in you main WHERE. You might add something else to the ORDER BY if you care which of the ties you get. If you want all the ties the you may need another layer.

Comment: i just need one, but its stillt not the minimal element right? It should be >= win/fail where card_id = lastId but from all of these, i want the element, where win/fail is minimal.